# Emulate Samsung Galaxy devices on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, emulation, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

Somebody knows how to emulate Samsung Galaxy Sx devices on Chrome? S6 and S10.

Is there somekind of calculation to find these settings: width, height, DPR?

There is only information to emulate in Android Studio and this one: https://www.danhendricks.com/2018/04/adding-iphone-galaxy-chrome-mobile-emulated-devices/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

https://www.mydevice.io/

This should help you in getting what you need. It has quite a good collection of phones.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try this http://screensiz.es/ It has a larger collection for what you need.